# Finite powers of fixed transcendentals

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, transcendental-numbers

I was thinking about the complex unit circle $S_1\subset\mathbb{C}$ as a group under multiplication and how, if possible, an element $z$ of infinite order could generate the circle itself. A friend quickly pointed out that $z$ cannot be algebraic, since there are points on $S_1$ with transcendental argument which cannot, by definition, be expressed as some polynomial of algebraic numbers. After mulling this over for a couple of minutes, I formulated the following question:

**Let $\tau$ be some fixed transcendental number. Can *any* trancendental number $\sigma$ be represented as $\tau^n + m$, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}, m\in\mathbb{Z}$?**

Comment: @2000 I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: @2000 I can't understand your question. The asker seems to be asking whether any transcendental number is some natural power of some fixed transcendental added to some integer, like fix $\;\pi\;$ , then for example is it possible to write $\;e=\pi^n+m\;$ for some $\;n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$ ?

Comment: OK , now I understand your question. But the answer is no. Because we have uncountable trancendental numbers.

Comment: See [Hamel Basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $S^1$ is not cyclic because it is uncountable. The set $\{\tau^n +m \mid n,m \in \Bbb Z\}$ is countable, hence it cannot be equal to the (uncountable) set of transcendental numbers.

---

However, you can say that $\tau^n + m$ is transcendental if $n≠0, m \in \Bbb Z$.

By [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), $\tau=e$ and $\sigma = e^{\sqrt 2}$ are [algebraically independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence) (and $\sigma$ is transcendental by the same theorem). In particular, you cannot write $\sigma = \tau^n + m$ for some integers $n$ and $m$.

[I don't known whether it is possible to write $e=π^n+m$ for some integers $n$ and $m$. I believe that it is still [unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62372/can-pi-be-a-root-of-a-polynomial-under-special-cases) ; at least the algebraic independence of $e$ and $π$ is [unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456097).]